# Compare two csv files and get data of Newly Added , Deleted , same/No change , Migrated

Tags: azure, powershell, shell, csv, azure-devops

I have 2 .csv files(old and New), they have matching columns, I am trying to compare the two and have a final output .csv that has the differences of

- If a row present in old file but Not in New file - Deleted
- If a row present in New File but Not in Old File - Newly added
- If a row present in Old file and New File        - No Change/same
- If a row Present in Old File and New File but with different content - Migrated from Old file to New File.

I got for Deleted, Newly added, No change. But I am not able to get  Migrated from Old file to New File.

**old.csv**

```
GENERATION,ENVIRONMENT,LAYER,LEVEL1,LEVEL2
GEN1,DEV,RA,FILES,MC
GEN1,PROD,RA,FILES,MC
GEN2,DEV,RA,FILES,MC
GEN2,PROD,RA,FILES,MC
GEN1,DEV,OUT,MC,
GEN1,PROD,OUT,MC,
GEN2,DEV,OUT,MC,
GEN2,PROD,OUT,MC,
GEN1,DEV,RA,FILES,GER
GEN1,DEV,OUT,GER,
```

**NewFile.csv**

```
GENERATION,ENVIRONMENT,LAYER,LEVEL1,LEVEL2
GEN1,DEV,RA,FILES,MS
GEN1,PROD,RA,FILES,MS
GEN2,DEV,RA,FILES,MS
GEN2,PROD,RA,FILES,MS
GEN1,DEV,OUT,MS,
GEN1,PROD,OUT,MS,
GEN2,DEV,OUT,MS,
GEN2,PROD,OUT,MS,
GEN1,DEV,RA,FILES,GER
GEN2,DEV,RA,FILES,GER
GEN1,DEV,OUT,GER,
GEN2,DEV,OUT,GER,
GEN1,DEV,OUT,RAM_CUSTOM_ADDED,
GEN2,PROD,RA,EXTERNAL,RAM_CUSTOM_ADDED
```

From above csv I want to get the Row which is included in old file and New File but with different data.

ex:
**oldFile.csv**

```
GEN1,DEV,RA,FILES,GER
GEN1,DEV,OUT,GER,
```

**NewFile.csv**

```
GEN1,DEV,RA,FILES,GER
GEN1,DEV,OUT,GER
GEN2,DEV,OUT,GER,
GEN2,DEV,RA,FILES,GER
```

Then I have to get the status as - Migrated from Old file to New File

```
    $reference = Import-Csv -Path '.\Downloads\Old File.csv'
    $results = Import-Csv -Path '.\Downloads\New File.csv'
    $Folder_Status_No_change = "No Change"
    $Folder_Status_Deleted = "Deleted"
    $Folder_Status_Newly_Added = "Newly Added"
    $Folder_Status_Migration = "Migrated from Old file to New File"
    $UserOutput = @()
    $Compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $reference -DifferenceObject $results -Property GENERATION,ENVIRONMENT,LAYER,LEVEL1,LEVEL2  -IncludeEqual 
    $Compare | Select-Object -unique GENERATION,ENVIRONMENT,LAYER,LEVEL1,LEVEL2,SideIndicator,
    @{N='Folder_Status';E={ForEach-Object {
    if($_.SideIndicator -eq "==")
    {
      $Folder_Status_No_change
    }
    elseif($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=")
    {
    $Folder_Status_Deleted 
    }
    elseif($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>")
    {
    $Folder_Status_Newly_Added 
    } 
    elseif($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" -xor $_.SideIndicator -eq "==" )
    {
    $Folder_Status_Migration 
    }
    }} } | Export-Csv -Path .\Downloads\Tst.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  One problem you're facing is the fact that Compare-Object only returns 3 comparison results (<=, =>, ==), but you want 4 results in your output.  As a work-around, define certain key fields, then check when "Newly added" values change on non-key fields only, and change the result to "Migrated from Old file to New File"; otherwise, if key fields changed, then theoretically, "Newly added" is the correct response.  Without defining key fields, all the values can change, and either "Newly added" or "Migrated from Old file to New File" are technically equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, can you please help me with code. I am bit confused.